# parsing an .kml file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, terminal

I am parsing an kml file which contains data like that:

```
<when>2013-08-15T15:00:39.744-07:00</when>
<gx:coord>13.7457943 52.0683374 0</gx:coord>
<when>2013-08-15T15:01:39.868-07:00</when>
<gx:coord>15.7458125 52.063955 0</gx:coord>
```

actually I like to parse that in bash so that I get `when` and `gx:coord` in one loop:

I got this far:

```
cat test.kml | grep -e "gx:coord" | while read line 
do
   echo $line
done
```

Which gives me all coords, and on the same way I would get the whens, read in a array I might achieve what I want, but there must be a better way :) Thnx in advance.

Comment: Can you install `xmlstarlet` (a proper XML parsing/generating toolkit accessible from bash)? Anything not involving a proper parser, in general, be an evil hack (see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14122).

Comment: To expound on *why* anything else would be a hack -- consider the case when your entries aren't separated by newlines; the KML format certainly doesn't require those newlines. Or consider the case when the namespace currently referred to as `gx` has a different prefix. Or the case where half of the `gx:coord` items are commented out, and you want to be able to exclude them. Or so forth.

Comment: By the way, to write an example of how to do this the right way, I'd need to know how the `xmlns:gx` attribute earlier in the file is set; the substrings given here aren't sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash if your lines are in order:

```
while read WHEN && read GXCOORD; do
    echo "$WHEN : $GXCOORD"
done < test.kml
```

Or perhaps do it this way:

```
while read WHEN && read GXCOORD; do
    echo "$WHEN : $GXCOORD"
done < <(exec grep -Fe "<when>" -e "<gx:coord>" test.kml)
```

And also perhaps trim out the tags:

```
while read WHEN && read GXCOORD; do
    WHEN=${WHEN##*'<when>'} WHEN=${WHEN%%'</when>'*}
    GXCOORD=${GXCOORD##*'<gx:coord>'} GXCOORD=${GXCOORD%%'</gx:coord>'*}
    echo "$WHEN : $GXCOORD"
done < <(exec grep -Fe "<when>" -e "<gx:coord>" test.kml)
```